# NSMutableDictionary memory leak - how do I fix it without crashing the App?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I must have misunderstood some of the memory management rules, because when I try to fix a memory leak, the App crashes. Let me show you some code:

calendarRequestLog is a property of type MutableDictionary in a singleton object, that exists as long as the App runs. Here's the declaration in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSMutableDictionary *calendarRequestLog;
```

I allocate it with (in init):

```
calendarRequestLog = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

I fill it with this (notice the retain, that creates the memory leak):

```
[calendarRequestLog setObject:[[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:delegate] retain] forKey:date];
```

I sometimes access it with this:

```
NSMutableArray* delegates = [calendarRequestLog objectForKey:date];
if(delegates != nil) {
   // add delegates
}
```

I empty it with this:

```
NSMutableArray* delegates = [calendarRequestLog objectForKey:date];    
if(delegates != nil) {
    for (id <ServerCallDelegate> delegate in delegates) { … }

    // clear the request from the log
    [calendarRequestLog removeObjectForKey:date];
}
```

Here's the code that crashes when I remove the retain above:

```
NSMutableArray* delegates = [calendarRequestLog objectForKey:date];
if(delegates != nil) {
    if([delegates containsObject:delegate]) // crash
        [delegates removeObject:delegate];
}
```

It crashes because delegates is deallocated but not nil. To be more precise, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS Exception.

All these methods may be called in different orders or multiple times.

I cannot figure out, why this happens. I thought, collections are supposed to retain their objects - as this array-object (delegates) is still in the collection, it should not be deallocated. Other code cannot be responsible, I showed you all occurrences of calendarRequestLog.

I appreciate all the help I can get!

@Edit
I think I got it.

I call the crashing method when the delegate gets deallocated, so that I do not call the delegate per accident later.

But: I retain the delegates in my calendarRequestLog, so it cannot get deallocated as long as this doesn't get called:

```
    // clear the request from the log
    [calendarRequestLog removeObjectForKey:date];
```

...which in turn, deallocates the delegate and calls the crashing method. As the calendarRequestLog has removed the delegates, but not yet the key, we crash.

Ok, I will solve this differently. Thanks for all the comments - thanks to you, I looked elsewhere!

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem. As you suspect, in [calendarRequestLog setObject:[[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:delegate] retain] forKey:date]; The retain is not necessary. I think the problem is in some code you're not including.

Comment: It should work without that `-retain`. Are you absolutely sure you don’t release that array in some part of your code, e.g. `[delegates release]`?

Comment: I am sure - delegates is always a local variable and I posted the contents of all functions that are accessing calendarRequestLog.

Comment: Maybe give some more code around the crash. You use the *delegate* variable... Can you guarantee that it is always a valid object or nil?

Comment: Can't you just use `[calendarRequestLog setObject:delegate forKey:date];`??? Why do you need an array for keeping the delegate in the dictionary? Looking at your code u have only one delegate to deal with...

Comment: @Cit if you found the problem, you should write up your solution as an answer and mark it as the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try retaining when fetching so nobody releases your object while you're using it?

```
NSMutableArray* delegates = [[calendarRequestLog objectForKey:date] retain];
if(delegates != nil) {
     if([delegates containsObject:delegate]) // crash
          [delegates removeObject:delegate];
}
[delegates release];
```

Answer (score -1):

Common practice is the following, because you already retain in the .h file:

```
//create local instance, then copy that to the class wide var
NSMutableDictionary *_calendarRequestLog = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.calendarRequestLog = _calendarRequestLog;
[_calendarRequestLog release];
```

Also, I don't really understand why you would retain here:

```
[calendarRequestLog setObject:[[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:delegate] retain] forKey:date];
```

Why not just change that to:

```
[calendarRequestLog setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:delegate] forKey:date];
```

Comment: Because the code crashed that way. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score -3):

Write instead

```
calendarRequestLog = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

this

```
self.calendarRequestLog = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

and try to use property instead ivar

Comment: In the first case the object is retained implicitly. And in the second the dictionary is autoreleased at creation and retained by using the accessor. Both are the same thing. But the first is preferred, because calls to `self` are discouraged in `init` and `dealloc` methods.